# Optimize a loop that calls a function multiple times in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, faker

I'm trying to find a more efficient way to do this;

Creating a data frame with pandas that calls a **faker** function that retrieves a string(a bunch of times) for each column.

```
import pandas as pd
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()

def createDF(size):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df["Name"] = [fake.name() for _ in range(size)]
    df["Email"] = [fake.free_email() for _ in range(size)]
    df["Address"] = [fake.address() for _ in range(size)]
    df["Phone"] = [fake.phone_number() for _ in range(size)]
    df["Comment"] = [fake.text() for _ in range(size)]
    return df
```

This are failed attempts to do so, just to showcase what I've already tried to do.

```
def create_0(size):
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {"Name": [fake.name() for _ in range(size)],
        "Email": [fake.free_email() for _ in range(size)],
        "Address": [fake.address() for _ in range(size)],
        "Phone": [fake.phone_number() for _ in range(size)],
        "Comment": [fake.text() for _ in range(size)]
        }
    )
    return df

def create_1(size):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df["Name"] = [fake.name()] * size
    df["Email"] = [fake.free_email()] * size
    df["Address"] = [fake.address()] * size
    df["Phone"] = [fake.phone_number()] * size
    df["Comment"] = [fake.text()] * size
    return df

def create_2(size):
    names = []
    emails = []
    addresses = []
    phones = []
    comments = []
    for _ in range(size):
        names.append(fake.name())
        emails.append(fake.name())
        addresses.append(fake.address())
        phones.append(fake.phone_number())
        comments.append(fake.text())
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":names,"Email":emails,"Address":addresses,"Phone":phones,"Comment":comments})
    return df

def create_3(size):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df["Name"] = list(itertools.repeat(df.apply(fake.name, axis=1), size))
    df["Email"] = list(itertools.repeat(df.apply(fake.free_email, axis=1), size))
    df["Address"] = list(itertools.repeat(df.apply(fake.address, axis=1), size))
    df["Phone"] = list(itertools.repeat(df.apply(fake.phone_number, axis=1), size))
    df["Comment"] = list(itertools.repeat(df.apply(fake.text, axis=1), size))
    return df


import itertools

def create_4(size):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df["Name"] = itertools.repeat((df.apply(lambda : fake.name(), axis=1)), size)
    df["Email"] = itertools.repeat((df.apply(lambda : fake.name(), axis=1)), size)
    df["Address"] = itertools.repeat((df.apply(lambda : fake.name(), axis=1)), size)
    df["Phone"] = itertools.repeat((df.apply(lambda : fake.name(), axis=1)), size)
    df["Comment"] = itertools.repeat((df.apply(lambda : fake.name(), axis=1)), size)
    return df
```

I've also read online different approaches with ***pandas*** .map and .Series but not very sure how to implement them.

Comment: It seems that the function has to be called that often to generate different names, email addresses,...? There can't be done very much then except maybe optimizing the fake function(s) itself.

Comment: How many rows of faked data do you seek? How long does each strategy currently take?  What is your target for acceptable time? What percent of your target is used by just `[fake.name() for _ in range(size)]`?

Comment: I don't really have a target, just wondering if there is a better technique or strategy to implement that result in a better performance.
I’ve currently testing with 1_000_000 rows to check the behavior in a very large data situation; 
createDF ~97s
create0    ~98s
create2    ~107s
create1 , create3 and create4  don’t work properly(just to show the idea I’m headed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to loop multiple times

```
def createDF(size):
    data= {'Name':[],
           'Email':[],
           'Address':[],
           'Phone':[],
           'Comment':[]}
    
    for _ in range(size):
        data['Name'].append(fake.name())
        data['Email'].append(fake.free_email())
        data['Address'].append(fake.address())
        data['Phone'].append(fake.phone_number())
        data['Comment'].append(fake.text())
    
    return pd.DataFrame(data)
```